# "Flagging is a way..." text on top of the own flags page is not translatable

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, international-sites, transifex

There is a new block of text on each one's flag page:

> Flagging is a way to bring inappropriate content or behavior to the attention of the community. See: [What is flagging?](/help/privileges/flag-posts) 
>   These are the flags that you have raised, along with their current status. You can filter this list using the links in the sidebar.

As seen in my own flag page in Stack Overflow en español:

> [image]

However, I cannot find this string in traducir.win, so right now the text is not translatable and shows in English instead of Spanish. The same happens to the rest of international Stack Overflow.

Comment: It looks like [those](https://traducir.win/string/12840) [strings](https://traducir.win/string/12839) are there now, actually I suggested a translation a few hours ago and it looks like they are imported already :D

Comment: @KacosPro I couldn't find them earlier today, not sure what happened (I did not search properly or maybe they weren't here yet). In any case, good to have them now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This seems fixed now](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current):

> [image: esSO]